# Change of states identification

Tags: time-series

Here I have a time series (the dots represent measured data, and the line connecting the dots was just added by excel)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9FYw.png

It clearly goes across 3 different states

- First is approximately linear, with some noise
- Then goes oscillatory
- Then turns into a smooth curve (all with noise)

The question is, what kind of mathematical tools would be appropriate to detect the changes of state?

I want to automate (code) the detection of the points were the changes of state occur.

I do not want to assume previos knowledge about what the time series represent, to avoid bias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"changes of state" to me means a change in model/parameters at one or more points in time. This requires ARIMA model identification and Intervention Detection with possible variance change points weights culminating in a sequential search process for break-points or "changes of state" . Why don't you post a csv file (one column excel file) of the data you graphed and I will try and help further.

For example data like this often arrive on our door step ..

and here

[image]

[image]

In order to automate an answer to this you would have to incorporate automatic procedures for the next four items.

1. ARIMA modelling
2. Intervention Detection
3. Model/Parameter change point detection
4. Error Variance change point detection

It might take a while to figure this out but if you are a skilled statistician and a skilled programmer it is definitely doable.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It took me some time to digest it. I'm a programmer, but not a statistician. The most important piece of data I get from your answer is "Intervention Detection" and "Model/Parameter change point detection"

Comment: why don't you post your data .. If u don't wish then you can contact me and I will try and help.

Comment: I still have not received real data, so I made a synthetic example, hoping to have some work started before I receive the data. I just added noise to a line, a sinusoidal and a parabola. Real data should look like this: http://www.scielo.br/img/revistas/riem/v6n5/a03fig10.jpg

Comment: It appears that the frequency of measurements (time interval) changes .. Is that so?

Comment: I guess that at constant intervals $\Delta t$, the series gets 2 lectures x(t) and y(t), but $\Delta t$ may not really be constant, because is experimental data.

Comment: time series analysis ( at least what I am comfortable with ) requires equally spaced observations thus intermediate points can be discarded.